# Column 'mary' does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

i'm doing a simple query here and it returns that column 'Mary' does not exist:

```
SELECT  telephone.telephonenumber as tel
FROM    person, telephone
WHERE   person.idperson = telephone.idperson
AND person.personname = ‘Mary’;
```

Can someone explain what can be happening? I don't want Mary as a column, but as a value.

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Comment: BTW, IIRC the ANSI SQL quoting rules are `'single quotes'` for literals, and `"double quotes"` for identifiers (column names, table names, etc) where required to handle spaces, case sensitivity, etc. Following these rules works with most databases, though MySQL requires `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI'` to accept it. That quoting is fine in MS SQL, in PostgreSQL, and in MySQL in ANSI mode.

Comment: Another very similar question was just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13219121/398670 . BTW, Gabriel, please accept Martin Smith's answer by clicking the tick below the score on his answer.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. I am Brazilian and the other user seems to be from a german-speaking country. Thanks a lot. I tried to accept Martin Smith's answer, but there was that time limit. Now it is accepted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use plain single quotes to delimit a string literal `'Mary'` not smart quotes `‘Mary’`

Comment: This is a good reason not to edit SQL in word processors. They love to "help" you and "fix" your "mistakes".

Comment: My professor asked a report with some SQL commands before implementing the database so it was just copying/pasting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are quoting your string correctly.

From your snippet, I'd say that's the problem here since you're using something else than simple single quotes.